# add a vScrollBar into my form

Tags: c#, windows, forms, scrollbar

I have the follow code and it works fine. Whenever I display the information I get a full windows but its been displayed that I have to make bigger the windows.I would like to insert a vScrollBar but I dont know how to make it work. I was able to insert it into my form but whenever I execute the windows the vScrollBar doesnt do anything

Here you have my code, thanks you all in advance

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestData
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            com.Dashboard proxy = new com.Dashboard();


            com.ProjectMetaData[] nc = proxy.GetAllProject();


            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


            foreach (com.ProjectMetaData value in nc)
            {
                /*sb.AppendLine(string.Join("\t",value.ProjectTitle
                    + string.Join("\t",value.ProjectID)
                    + string.Join("\t",value.PublishStatus)));*/
                sb.AppendLine("\r");
                sb.AppendLine(value.ProjectTitle + "       " + value.ProjectID + "       " + value.PublishStatus);

            }
            //StringBuilder.StringBuilder();
            label1.Text = sb.ToString(); 
        }

        public void vScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple.

1. Set your forms's `AutoScroll` Property to `true`.
2. Now Just add some content that is larger to fit on the current screen size and you will see your
   vertical Scroll Bar.

**Screenshot while the scroll bar is at Top.**

[image: Screenshot while the scroll bar is at top.]

**Screenshot while the scroll bar is at Bottom.**

[image: Screenshot while the scroll bar is at bottom.]

Comment: _Now Just add some content that is larger to fit on the current screen size and you will see your vertical Scroll Bar._ Well this is true but it is also true without adding a panel. Simply setting the form to autoscroll is enough.

Comment: @TaW I had the screenshots of the `Panel` already, that's why. I will edit and change my answer... Thank you :)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I have a question, ho I can add thins panel inside the button that already have? this is because whenever the button is press it will display all the information that I will need to view inside the panel. thanks again

Comment: @user3790916 I don't understand what you are asking? Anyways I have  changed my answer, check it you do not have to add the panel...

Comment: Hi, I am sorry I was asking you at the same time that you were updating your answer. I worked super!!!! thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @user3790916 If this helped you please select it as answer by selecting the tick symbol beside my answer and upvote it :P